# How can I show Hamburger button instead of this "a"?

Tags: wordpress, mobile, wordpress-theming, themes, hamburger-menu

How can I show the Hamburger button instead of this "a" in my mobile View?
Website: https://checkmateoutfit.com/

[image: Screenshot of Mobile View]

This is the error I am getting:

checkmateoutfit.com/:1

```
   Access to font at 'https://www.checkmateoutfit.com/wp-content/themes/voevod/assets/css/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0' from origin 'https://checkmateoutfit.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

[image: Errors]

Tried this code to add in .htaccess but not worked.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$">
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: https://www.checkmateoutfit.com/wp-content/themes/voevod/assets/css/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0 this font is not loading

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to take the tour and read this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: updated my question, kindly review this.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself, there was an issue with the website and WordPress URLs.
Did https://checkmateoutfit.com/ instead of https://www.checkmateoutfit.com/
and problem solved.
Because It was working without www before, IDK why the Bluehost support agent changed it to https://www.checkmateoutfit.com/.